# Subset Sum for {1,...,n}

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, subset-sum

In general, the subset sum problem is NP-Complete. However, what if we say that our set is $\{1,...,n\}$? Is there a formula/combinatorial calculation that says how many subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$ have their sum equal to $k$?

Comment: You can calculate this easily using dynamic programming. Try it out.

Comment: Of course I can, there is a dynamic programming algorithm for Subset Sum. My question is whether there exists a formula or a combinatorial reasoning for this since this is a trivial and fixed set.

Comment: additionally, how to prove that there is at least one solution for every k <= 0.5n(n+1) ?

Comment: @AlbertHendriks maybe I am missing your point but you can always take the singleton {k}

Comment: @AlbertHendriks You can easily prove this by induction.

Comment: @TheNotMe I'm assuming k can be greater than n?

Comment: Ah. Yes. My bad (too tired).

Comment: @AlbertHendriks you can prove it by induction. Assume that the property holds for $k$ and try proving it for $k+1$ just adding to the subset ${k+1}$ when you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [A053632](http://oeis.org/A053632). The prefixes of this sequence convergence to the more well-known [A000009](http://oeis.org/A000009), the number of partitions into distinct (or odd) parts. You shouldn't expect a clean formula, though it's of course easy to calculate small terms using dynamic programming.